# Converting repeating rows to columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe with repeating rows into columns as follows

```
INPUT
Key  |  Value
A    |  1
B    |  2
C    |  3
A    |  4
B    |  5
C    |  6

EXPECTED OUTPUT
A  |  B  |  C
1  |  2  |  3
4  |  5  |  6
```

There are a lot of options like pivot(), unstack(), groupby(), etc. But, I was unsure of using it with just 2 columns as shown in the input.

Comment: Refer to Question 10

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot! Yes, that answers my question

Comment: @Ch3steR In my opinion its not a straight forward pivot. Please check my answer and let me know if I have missed anything obvious.

Comment: @Ch3steR after looking at q.10 agree that its a dupe - same as my answer pretty much.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Question 10 is the exact same as what OP wanted. The one with `GroupBy.cumcount` and `df.pivot`

Comment: @Ch3steR Oh ok. I answered it in another way. Should I remove my solution or can I keep it?

Comment: @MayankPorwal One more way to solve the question. Why delete it?

Comment: Great. I'll keep it then.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a straight-forward `pivot`. Do this using [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
In [747]: x = df.pivot(index=None, columns='Key', values='Value').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))

In [748]: x
Out[748]: 
Key    A    B    C
0    1.0  2.0  3.0
1    4.0  5.0  6.0
```

### Explanation:

Let's break it down:

First you pivot your `df` like this:

```
In [751]: y = df.pivot(index=None, columns='Key', values='Value')

In [752]: y
Out[752]: 
Key    A    B    C
0    1.0  NaN  NaN
1    NaN  2.0  NaN
2    NaN  NaN  3.0
3    4.0  NaN  NaN
4    NaN  5.0  NaN
5    NaN  NaN  6.0
```

Now we are close to your expected output, but we need to remove `Nan` and collapse the 6 rows into 2 rows.

For that, we convert each column to a `pd.Series` and `dropna()`:

```
In [753]: y.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))
Out[753]: 
Key    A    B    C
0    1.0  2.0  3.0
1    4.0  5.0  6.0
```

This is your final output.

Comment: Could you please explain what the lambda function is doing?

Comment: @GaganG I've added explanation. Please check.